# Loop through files removing stop-words

Tags: python, python-3.x

I want to remove stop-words from multiple files in a local folder. I know how to do it for one file, but I can't get my head around doing it for all files in that folder.

What I embarrassingly tried:

```
import io
from nltk.corpus import stopwords
from nltk.tokenize import word_tokenize
import glob
import os
import codecs


stop_words = set(stopwords.words('english'))

for afile in glob.glob("*.txt"):
    file1 = open(afile)
    line = file1.read()
    words = word_tokenize(line)
    words_without_stop_words = ["" if word in stop_words else word for word in words]
    new_words = " ".join(words_without_stop_words).strip()
    appendFile = open('subfolder/file1.txt','w')
    appendFile.write(new_words)
    appendFile.close()
```

I don't even know how far I could get with this, because I get:

> Traceback (most recent call last):
>     File "C:\Desktop\neg\sw.py", line 14, in 
>       line = file1.read()
>     File "C:\Program Files\Python36\lib\encodings\cp1252.py", line 23, in decode
>       return codecs.charmap_decode(input,self.errors,decoding_table)[0]
>   UnicodeDecodeError: 'charmap' codec can't decode byte 0x9d in position 1757: character maps to `<undefined>`

I tried using glob, but I can't find a good documentation. Maybe it is not necessary?

Comment: I think at least you should use `open('subfolder/file1.txt','a')` instead because 'w' will cause to overwrite the file everytime you use it. I am supposing that you are storing all non-stop words in the same file.

Comment: It is nice to show the error message, but it would be better to give the full stacktrace to know at what line the error was raised. And when it comes to encoding question, you should also say what is the exact Python version and the OS.

Comment: The error message indicates that the input file is not a Unicode file. We can't guess what it is without seeing the individual bytes around the error. See the [Stack Overflow `character-encoding` tag info page](/tags/character-encoding/info) for some troubleshooting tips and instructions for how to post a good, well-defined question.

Comment: @SergeBallesta updated the error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to add the encoding format while writing into file that is `utf-8` normally you can do this using

```
appendFile = open('subfolder/file1.txt','w', encoding='utf-8')
appendFile.write(new_words)
appendFile.close()
```

Instead of writing data into file you have to append data into file so that all data store into single file.

You can also use codecs for inserting into file like

```
f = codecs.open(filename, encoding="utf-8")
```

and insert the data.

Answer (score 1):

Seems like the encoding is wrong for your file. You will need to call [open()](https://kite.com/python/docs/builtins.open) function with proper `encoding` kwarg (it might be `"utf-8"`). And use `'a'` when you want to append your file. I would actually open the append file before working with files and close it after all files has been written.

When filtering your words from stopwords do not put empty strings into the list, just omit those words:

```
words_without_stop_words = [word for word in words if word not in stop_words]
new_words = " ".join(words_without_stop_words).strip()
```

Answer (score 1):

From the full stacktrace, you are using a Windows system with a Western European language and a default Ansi code page 1252.

One of your files contains a 0x9d byte. At read time, Python tries to decode the file bytes to unicode strings and fails because 0x9d is not a valid CP1252 byte, hence the error.

What can be done?

The correct way is to identify the offending file and try to identify its real encoding. A simple way would be to display its name:

```
for afile in glob.glob("*.txt"):
    with open(afile) as file1:
        try:
            line = file1.read()
        except UnicodeDecodeError as e:
            print("Wrong encoding file", afile, e)       # display file name and error
            continue                                     # skip to next file
    ...
```

Alternatively, if the error only happen if few words of few files, you could simply ignore or replace the offending bytes:

```
for afile in glob.glob("*.txt"):
    with open(afile, errors = "replace") as file1:
        line = file1.read()
    ...
```